# Help storing data in Android

Tags: android, save

I have a button which stores whatever text is written in the text form above it when clicked. However, the application force closes when the button is clicked. What could be the problem?

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String FILEOUTPUT = Day;
        BufferedWriter bfw;

        try {
            bfw = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(FILEOUTPUT));
            Scanner scan = new Scanner((File) editData.getText());

            bfw.write(scan.nextLine());
            bfw.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I bet you can't cast the return of `editData.getText()` into a `File` object

Comment: What is the proper syntax to assign the text from EditText to a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to first look at the reported Exception from DDMS in these cases. Can you provide the reported exception from DDMS?
Where is editData? Is it an EditText or a TextView ? You are casting a String to a File directly in that line, instead you should be creating a File object.

should be like:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(editData.getText()));
```

Comment: It's an EditText. I changed the syntax to yours and it no longer force closed, but editData.getText() doesn't return a file object, so I have to cast it somehow. Casting it as a String allows the code to compile, but the code doesn't work properly (doesn't display the Toast message).

Comment: I'm guessing that you keep file path or name in editData, so when you retrieve this path from editData.getText(), you should create a File instance, with "new File(filename)" part.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You said "editData.getText() doesn't return a file object". It's normal since it should return a String, which is (I'm guessing) your file path read from that EditText. You say you casted that to String, so actually you casted a String to String again, which has no effect. But instead of reading from file, you read from that String by executing "Scanner(String source)" when you should have used "Scanner(File filename)" method.

Comment: If you use the exact line that I pasted in my original answer: "Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(editData.getText()));" , I believe your problem will be solved.